# I am trying to use a switch inside a switch based on answers chosen

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have searched through looking for my answer in other questions and while some are close to what I need the answers for them do not seem to work for me.

I am trying to use a switch inside a switch that is all based off of answers to questions. I have tried many ways to get this to work to no prevail.

If question 1 is answered with Yes then I need question 1a to be checked for an answer too. If 1a is then answered with a Yes then I need 1aa to be checked for an answer as well. If 1aa is answered Yes then 1aaa is skipped, but if 1aa is answered No then 1aaa is checked for an answer. Example is below -->

```
// check session type

    if (!$_POST['sessionType'])

    $errors[] = "Your \"Preference\" is required";

// check which sessionType then validate for answer

    switch($_POST['sessionType']){

    case 'Answer1':

// check Answer1

        if (!$_POST['Q1answer'])

            $errors[] = "Please answer question with Yes or No";

            break;

// START SWITCH

    switch($_POST['Yes'])

    case 'YesPlease':

        if (!$_POST['YesPlease'])

            errors[] = "Please and YesPlease or NoThanks";

            break;

    switch($_POST['NoThanks'])

    case 'NoThanks':

         if (!$_POST['NoThanks'])

             errors[] = "Please tell us why not";

             break;

// Move on to next Q

     case 'Answer2':

// check question 2

        if (!$_POST['Q2answer'])

            $errors[] = "Please answer Yes or No";

            break;

      switch($_POST['Yes'])

    case 'YesPlease':

        if (!$_POST['YesPlease'])

            errors[] = "Please and YesPlease or NoThanks";

            break;  }

// END SWITCH
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

switch within a switch really makes code hard to read, consider using if statements instead.

```
$condition1 = 1;
$condition2 = 3;

switch ($condition1) {

    case 1:

        switch ($condition2) {

            case 1:
                // do something
                break;

            case 2:
                // do something
                break;

            default:
                throw new \Exception('unknown condition');
                break;

        }
        break;

    case 2:
        // do something
        break;

    default:
        throw new \Exception('unknown condition');
        break;

}
```

Comment: I don't mind the code being hard to read. I understand it and I will be the only one to read it. This is just a small questionnaire that gets sent to certain clients I have and not used regularly. Plus that would mean re-writing a few hundred lines of code as there are a lot of questions that run off of each other.